# iPhone 7 running iOS 14.3 can't make WhatsApp calls over WiFi

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

My iPhone 7 (iOS 14.3) will no longer make calls - audio nor video - over WiFi. I have tried re-installing WhatsApp and although it then asks me to grant permission to the microphone / camera / etc, it does not ask me for permission to use the Local Network.

I have checked Settings->Privacy->Local Network and WhatsApp does not appear in the list. Similarly if i look in Settings->WhatsApp, there is no setting for Local Network at all.

I have tried **Reset the network settings**, **Reset all settings**, and also just went through the **Erase all content and settings**. Following this I set the phone up again from scratch, downloaded WhatsApp and the situation is exactly the same.

Any ideas why WhatsApp wont use the Local Network? Other mobile devices on the same WiFi network work fine.

**UPDATE**

I have connected the iPhone to my Mac and been running Console.app as I tried to make a WhatsApp voice call. The following error is generated but I cannot find any information about this process:
[image]

Confirmed that this error does not occur when my other iPhone (a 5S, connected to the same WiFi network) makes a WhatsApp voice call.

Comment: What started this?  Was is working prior to a specific incident or update?

Comment: what happens exactly?

Comment: Prior to updating to iOS 14.3 it worked fine. Now, all calls just immediately fail. Same with FaceTime.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this happens as the microphone on the device is broken. It manifested itself as follows:

- Device still plays audio but phone calls using the native Phone produced no audio and the option to put the call on speakerphone was greyed out.
- Siri would not respond.
- WhatsApp voice calls would be attempted and immediately fail.
- Clicking the microphone button in the Translate app would cause the app to immediately crash out.

Hope this helps someone in future.