# Cannot make WhatsApp calls on WIFI on iOS 15 : local network access required, but WhatsApp absent from the apps list

Tags: ios, wifi, whatsapp.app

WhatsApp on iPhone is currently unable to successfully complete a voice call. The incoming call is notified by the usual ringtone and answer controls on the screen, but upon answering the call, nothing can be heard. Several seconds later, the call is cancelled, and a dialogue briefly appears, instructing me to give local network access to WhatsApp, by going. into iOS Settings > Privacy > local network, and allow access:

[image]

Here is the issue however: WhatsApp is not present in the list of apps, so I cannot toggle the switch to “enable “:

[image]

I have tried two things:

1. reinstalling WhatsApp, hoping that would reset things, and cause it
   to ask for permission again
2. resetting the privacy settings: Settings > General > Transfer or Reset
   iPhone > Reset > Reset Location & privacy
3. checked this question: [iPhone 7 running iOS 14.3 can't make WhatsApp calls over WiFi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411873/iphone-7-running-ios-14-3-cant-make-whatsapp-calls-over-wifi)

But the dialogue did not show, and WIFI calls still fail.

The WIFI connection itself is fine (other network activities such as email and web browsing, work fine). WhatsApp calls work fine on cellular data, and the chat function works ok on both WIFI and cellular data.

How can prompt an app to ask again for local network access?
... and/or
is there any way of adding a specific app to that list in the local network settings?

iOS version: 15.4.1

WhatsApp version: 2.22.8.75